# Contact Form 7 - Display Dropdown, Send Different Data

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Is it possible to have a dropdown on Contact Form 7 with a dropdown list of First names only, but for the data to send the first and last name?
For example, the dropdown says, "John", but the data sent is "John Smith"? Thank you

Comment: This is a question for the plugin's support team. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and you can [see an example here](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/) on the Contact Form 7 website.

For example:

```
[select your-field "Label 1|value1" "Label 2|value2" "Label 3|value3"]
```

The actual value is hidden in the front-end form (label and value appear the same), however in the "Mail" tab of your form admin, you can send the actual value using the `[_raw_{field name}]`, so in the case of my example `[your-field]` would return Label 1, Label 2 etc and `[_raw_your-field]` would return value1, value2 etc.